# Enabling wireless network access

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ipad, isp

I have an internet connection with a speed of 512 kbps. I recently bought an Ipad and wanted to have wifi access. Despite buying a wireless router myself, my ISP is not allowing to set up a wireless network. They are holding back the proxy IP address for wireless router and would only release if I upgrade my plan which is insane since I use very limited bandwidth ( upto 2gb per month) and was not mentioned of this clause when I had the connection.

Is there a way I can set up my wireless router without involving the ISP ? If not I have to change to others who are already offering wireless access in the same plan and price.

Answer (score 1):

You could just go out and buy a wireless router and connect it to the modem/router the ISP gave you. This would be an easy alternative if this job requires hacking. A wireless router could cost you only 40 USD. Just make sure that you set up security on the wireless router, or other people could use it too!